# Sometimes publishing an item auto-selects all boxes

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, content-management

I can't wrap my head around this one.

We have a sitecore environment with a large number of languages. Sometimes when attempting to publish an item, we'll see every single checkbox selected (all languages, Sub Items, Related Items, all environments, etc).

I've tried to figure out the main cause of this because when people are swift to pull the trigger on publishing they could accidentally publish all sub-items & related items in all languages. It's an unnecessary headache to put it lightly.

Any ideas on what it could be? I've considered managing users permissions but ideally this wouldn't be the solution. I'm looking more to find the actual root cause of why this is occurring in the first place. If there's a solution regardless I'd take it but quite honestly I'm also curious how everything is being auto-selected at all.

I'm on ver. 9.3 if that helps.

My original assumption was that this was tied to someone accidentally selecting all boxes and publishing, but there is quite literally no feasible or logical reason to do so, so something must be causing it elsewhere.

I tried to determine the times in which it occurs but it seems somewhat sporadic? Can't nail anything down there either.

Comment: Are you using the Sitecore Publishing Service?

Comment: @SebastianLay yes.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely not possible that `Smart`/`Republish` radio button, `Subitems` and `Related items` checkboxes and language checkboxes are selected automatically on their own.

All their values are coming from user registry settings - they are saved together with user profile information.

From what you wrote, I assume that you use same account for multiple users. Don't. Disable default `admin` account and create separate account for every user that logs in to Sitecore.

If any of the users still checks all the options mentioned in your question, it will be easy to find out who it is and take appropriate actions.

Comment: We do not use the same account for multiple users. That is part of the confusion. Each user has their own account.

Are you saying that each user would be logged as checking every box every time this is done?